# IIS Rewrite Global Rule

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

Recently the site I was working on added language handling in this way: content tailored toward users of a certain language will have urls that start with `baseUrl/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/...` (I may be more explicit since this will catch a lot of things that will not work for my use case). The default language will not. The current default language has a lot of rewrite rules and I want a way to globally set up the input used with the rewriter to either be URL path after '/' or after `([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/)?` which should be directly after the '/'. The only thing I have thought of that seems to work is convert each rule to a regex and add `([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/)?` to the beginning of every rule. Basically I want to apply the rewrite rules I have to sub domains of this site.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not stop processing after each rewrite rule you could add a rule to "stuff" the language into a server variable which is essentially an HTTP header (Lookup allowed server variables). You can process your rules as normal and then rewrite the language back in if a header value is detected.

Comment: That's a neat idea but in my case it would take a good deal of refactoring since a bunch of these rules stop processing.

Comment: Is the URL pattern match the same for all rules at the moment?

Stopping processing makes it a little trickier, if you are dead set on not touching the rewrite rules you could use Application Request Routing and setup a proxy site in front of your app site, do your rewriting there as per above and then rewrite the language back in on your app site. If you do I would suggest looking at enabling disk based caching if it suits your site and content.